# How can I define argv[2] to be a list as per the following code, and can be called at runtime?

Tags: c, linux

argv[2] - It contains a list of items such as 0x1, 0x2, 0x3.

Suppose we execute our program like this(runtime) - ./program -i all

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    // an array of character arrays.
    argv[2] = { "0x1", "0x2", "0x3" }; //How can we define argv[2] by a variable name, like for example : argv[2] is all. So, all = { "0x1", "0x2", "0x3" }; 
    return 0;
}
```

Note : all is also argv[2].

Instead of ./program -i 0x1 0x2 0x3, I wish to do like this ./program -i all (where all = { "0x1", "0x2", "0x3" }.

Comment: You cannot. You can use the `{ "0x1", "0x2", "0x3" }` to initialize an *array* of pointers to char but the type of `argv[2]` is a pointer to char.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin , if possible could you share a sample program to help me understand better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You program needs to explicitly check for the string "all" in the parameter list, then do something different when it finds it.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int my_argc;
    char **my_argv;
    if (argc > 2) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[2], "all")) {
            my_argc = 3;
            my_argv = (char *[]){ "0x1", "0x2", "0x3" };
        } else {
            my_argc = argc - 2;
            my_argv = argv + 2;
        }
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<my_argc; i++) {
            handle_arg(my_argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
             my_argv = argv + 2;
                     ^
 warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
         for (i=0; i<my_argv; i++) {
                    ^
The program reports these errors however, if feasible could you post the whole program for better understanding please? Also what does handle_arg function do? @dbush

Comment: @PragyaGupta Removed `const` from the `argv` declaration which shouldn't have been there, and used `my_argc` instead of `my_argv` in the loop.

Comment: @PragyaGupta `handle_arg` is just a sample of something you could do with each argument.

Comment: doesn't this function handle_arg execute only for one address and not multiple addresses in one go?

Comment: @anoymous_guy Currently it takes one at a time, but you can change it to accept an array.

Answer (score 0):

You would pass those items to the executable:

```
./a.out 0x1 0x2 0x3
```

Then in your program, argv[1] = "0x1", argv[2] = "0x2", etc.

Comment: is it not possible to excute something like this ./a.out all wherein all = 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 (done inside the code)?